# What is meaning of vector ordering in $\mathbb R^n$ by a non-empty convex cone $?$

Tags: vectors

What is meaning of vector ordering in $\mathbb R^n$ by a non-empty convex cone $?$

How could  we  create a pseudo order relation in $\mathbb R^n$ using this convex cone $?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convex cone $K$ defines a partial ordering by the relation:
$$
x \le y \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad  y-x \in K
$$
More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone#Partial_order_defined_by_a_convex_cone).